# how to access variable of subscribe block of behaviour subject outside the block

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am using behaviour subject and subscribe it in ts file.

trying to access the variable outside the subject block in ts file..

code for service.ts

````
 private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService
  ) {
  }

  // try

  sendMessage(value: any) {
   this.messageSource.next(value);
  }

  get getMessage() {
    return this.messageSource.asObservable();
    
   }```

now in TS file
````

ngOnInit() {

// this.viewUser = this.commonService.getMessage;

```
this.subscription = this.commonService.getMessage.subscribe(value => {
  this.viewUser = value; 
  console.log(this.viewUser)
 });


 console.log(this.viewUser)
```

}

file console showing data..
but in second console , it is showing inital value of behaviour subject ie. null
how can i get data outside the block

Comment: Have you tried to make `messageSource` public, and subscribe on it directly (without using `asObservable()` method?

Comment: yes, i i have tried it.

Answer (score 0):

What's inside your `subscribe` is running asynchronously.

```
this.subscription = this.commonService.getMessage.subscribe(value => {
  this.viewUser = value; 
  console.log(this.viewUser)
 });

console.log(this.viewUser) // <-- This is running before what's inside subscribe
```

You could use the `async` `await` to make the function async and whats inside sync :

```
this.viewUser = await this.commonService.getMessage.asPromise();
```

The function containing this code should be `async`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would say there is *no* way to access an asynchronous variable (`this.viewUser` here) synchronously.

However since you're using `BehaviorSubject`, there exists a cheeky way to access it's value synchronously. If you notice, a `BehaviorSubject` is created with a default value. In other words it *always* holds some value. RxJS provides a [`getValue()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.5.5/src/internal/BehaviorSubject.ts#L32) function (or the [`value`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.5.5/src/internal/BehaviorSubject.ts#L19) getter - they are synonymous) to synchronously get the value held by the `BehaviorSubject`. So in your case you could do the following

Service

```js
public messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);   // <-- public

constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

sendMessage(value: any) {
  this.messageSource.next(value);
}

get getMessage() {
  return this.messageSource.asObservable();
}
```

Component

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.viewUser = this.commonService.messageSource.getValue();
  console.log(this.viewUser);
}
```

There are multiple disadvantages

1. It's considered an anti-pattern and usually frowned upon since you lose the async behavior.
2. Say the statement `this.viewUser = this.commonService.messageSource.getValue();` is executed before the function `sendMessage()` in the service, you'd be assigning the value `null` to the variable `this.viewUser`. And the variable won't be updated automatically akin to the async behavior with a subscription.

Answer (score 0):

`Observables` are new way of handling `async` requests. Subscriptions to `Observables` are quite similar to calling a `function`. But where `Observables` are different is in their ability to return multiple values called `streams`.Observables not only able to return a value synchronously, but also asynchronously.

In your case first the second `console.log(this.viewUser)` is executed which is not initialized with the subscription and because of that you get `null` first and then your `subscription` evaluated. You can try this:

**app.component.ts**

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.commonService.getMessage.subscribe(value => {
    this.viewUser = value; 
    console.log(this.viewUser)
    this.logViewUser();
  });
}

logViewUser() {
  console.log(this.viewUser)
}

 console.log(this.viewUser)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to share data between sibling components by using [TypeScript Setter and Getter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) instead of an Observable (which we must need to unsubscribe to prevent memory leak).

**service.ts**

```
  _message: string;

  set message(value: any) {
    this._message = value;
  }

  get message() {
    return this._message;
  }
```

Set value from any component or service etc

```
this.commonService.message = 'some message';
```

And finally get the value without any subscription etc

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.viewUser = this.commonService.message
 console.log(this.viewUser);
}
```