# Use Subject or BehaviourSubject to alert a component, through a service, that something happened?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular10

On an Angular 10 application I need to send a message between components so I created the service:

```
export class MemoService {

  private subject = new Subject<Memo>();

  send(code: MemoCode, data?: any) {
    this.subject.next(new Memo(code, data));
  }

  clear() {
    this.subject.next();
  }

  get(): Observable<Memo> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }

}
```

On a component consuming this service I have:

```
  private memo: Subscription;

  private user: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);


  constructor(private memoService: MemoService) { 

    this.getUser().subscribe((result: GetUserResponse) => this.user.next(result));

    this.memo = this.memoService.get().subscribe((memo: Memo) => { 

      if (memo.code == MemoCode.AuthenticatedUserModified) 
        this.getUser().subscribe((result: GetUserResponse) => this.user.next(result));

    });

  }
```

The idea is when a specific User is updated I send a `Memo` to other components using the `MemoService`.

**Question**

Should I use Subject or BehaviorSubject in both Component and Service?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject

Comment: what is the purpose of using subject in the component?

Comment: @RafiHenig Any moment ComponentA sends a new Memo ComponentB needs to know about it and act accordantly the MemoCode. You're saying that MemoService's subject should be only an Observable?

Comment: I would suggest of using a single BehaviorSubject/ReplaySubject in the service

Comment: I think I will ReplaySubject as it seems similar to BehaviorSubject but without an initial value which I don't have.

Comment: I would rather recommend using simple setter and getter to achieve this, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63896191/how-to-access-variable-of-subscribe-block-of-behaviour-subject-outside-the-block/63897453#63897453

Comment: @KamranKhatti What if a new value is sent?

Comment: @MiguelMoura you can set new value from any component using that service set method, same as you set value in subject.

Comment: @MiguelMoura What is the use of `user: BehaviorSubject<User>` in the component? I mean what is the role it is playing to notify other components?

Comment: @user2216584 It is used to display the user.name in a menu, to check if the user has a Role and can view or not part of the UI, ...

Answer (score 1):

> The idea is when a specific User is updated I send a Memo

I think you might be making it harder than necessary. You may not need the "MemoService" at all!

The idea with observables is that you can subscribe and always have the latest value automatically.  Your subscription to `getUser()` should already produce the updated value when changes occur.  There should be no need for consuming components to re-emit values.

In this case, the only place a Subject would be needed, is in your `UserService`.

```
export class UserService{

  private user = new BehaviorSubject<User>(undefined);
  public user$ = this.user.asObservable();

  setUser(user: User) {
    this.user.next(user);
  }

  updateUser(changes: Partial<User>) {
    const updatedUser = { ...this.user.value, ...changes };
    this.user.next(updatedUser);
  }
}
```

Then, your component code is super simple:

```
class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  public user$ = this.userService.user$;
}
```

Any component can call `userService.setUser()` and all interested components will automatically receive the updated value.

Notice you don't even need to subscribe in the controller and can simply use the `async` pipe in your template:

```
<div *ngIf="user$ | async as user">
  <h1>Hello {{ user.name }}!</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're trying to do seems to be state management, i.e. managing shared state between components. If that's the case, I would strongly advise against using manual solutions like services and subjects, but rather use some battle-tested state management library. Some good ones are:

https://datorama.github.io/akita/

https://ngrx.io/

https://www.ngxs.io/

Comment: Yes, I am kind of doing that but only in a simple case ... Using one of those, at least for now, would be to much in this specific case. That is why I created this simple service.